# Get total number of characters of values of keys of json object

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to get total number of characters of values of keys of JSON object. Currently I was able only to take all the keys length and sum them. Is there any other way?

```
$.getJSON('lib/get-details.html', function(data) {
   var total = data.reg_name.length + data.reg_org.length + data.reg_street.length; // 82
    // var total = data.keys of value length...
});
```

Is there anyway to take that directly like on second line?

Comment: What is the problem with the current way?

Comment: @vlzvl I have about 30 keys.

Comment: I see. A loop comes to mind.

Comment: @vlzvl hmm... I was thinking on smth, but don't know where to start, there is no var_dump in jquery.

Comment: no `var_dump` but you can use `console.log(data)` to check out the structure.

Comment: looks like this  `Object { twitter_followers=3, facebook_likes=7, google_plus_one=0.......`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the jQuery map function

```
$.getJSON('lib/get-details.html', function(data) {
  total = $.map(data, function(v){ return v; }).join('').length;
});
```